# php - Return array based on range key

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array with of enumerating numbers, like:

```
$pageNumbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

Now I have an active page number `$currentPage` and want to have based on this, before and after 2 elements - a total number of 5.

`$currentPage = 2`:

Return: `array(1,2,3,4,5)`

`$currentPage = 6`

Return: `array(4,5,6,7,8)`

`$currentPage = 10`

Return: `array(6,7,8,9,10)`

Unfortunately, I did not come up with an elegant and simple method to solve this (2x while, 1 big foreach and so on). Maybe you have an idea.

My first idea was:

```
foreach ($pageNumbers as $page) {
        if($page < $currentPage+3 && $page > $currentPage-3) {
            array_push(...);
        }
    }
```

This will work for the `$currentPage = 6`, but if `$currentPage = 1`, it will only return `1,2,3`.

Comment: nevertheless, please show what you've got. Was is working? What was the problem?

Comment: `array_search` and `array_splice` would work fine.

Comment: Have you considered to find the index of the current page and then trimming the array either side?

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I added my tryout.

Comment: `range($start,$end)` and then a tiny bit of math and some checks for first and last page,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array_slice and cut out the part of the array you need.

I use an if to see where to slice the array.

```
if($currentPage < 3){
    $arr = array_slice($pageNumbers,0,5);
}elseif($currentPage > count($pageNumbers)-2){
    $arr = array_slice($pageNumbers,-5,5);
}else{
    $arr = array_slice($pageNumbers,$currentPage-3,5);
}
```

See working example below.
https://3v4l.org/fpOFQ